# Which book should I refer to for analytical solid geometry?

Tags: undergraduate-education, textbooks, geometry

I am an undergraduate student and since this is a site of math educators, I thought of putting this question (more accurately a query) here. Can you list  some good books on analytical solid geometry?

Comment: This seems to be more about mathematical content than the process of learning mathematics (unless you add such an angle to it), so I think math.SE might be more appropriate. Other than that, your question could be more specific. Have you searched for such books already? If what you found does not satisfy you, why is that? What are some properties that you want to see in a good book?

Comment: For reference I use the CRC Handbook of Mathematical Tables.  Some of the older editions have different presentations of solid (Euclidean) geometry.  If you were more specific about your needs, someone here might mention a resource to fill them.  Gerhard "Is There Analytical Gaseous Geometry?" Paseman, 2015.10.30

Comment: There are hundreds of such books freely available on the internet, for example [consider this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Solid+Geometry%22&tbm=bks&tbs=bkv:r), perhaps including "analytic" as an additional word in the search words. And if for some reason these are not available in your country, just google the title and author of selected books that show up in the search I just did and do a separate search for them individually for digitized versions that are available to you (e.g. at Hathitrust or at archive.org).

Comment: @Dave L Renfro thanks a ton....my problem was I could not find books on this topic other than those of Indian author and which were mostly substandard...... following the recipe : formulae, exercise, repeat.

Comment: Since this question recently got bumped to the top of the queue, I'll use this opportunity to essentially reproduce a comment, which I made a few days ago in a Mathematics Stack Exchange question, that might also be helpful to anyone landing on this page: See my answer to [A good Open Source book on Analytic Geometry?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/165870/13130). Many of these books are on the internet --- google the author and title with "archive.org". Two books that I especially recommend (each is very detailed and complete, **(continued)**

Comment: as well as written by eminent experts in both mathematics and mathematical exposition) are [**Elements of Analytical Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.177084/page/n3/mode/2up) by George Alexander Gibson and Peter Pinkerton (1911) and [**Plane and Solid Analytic Geometry**](https://archive.org/details/planeandsolidan02graugoog) by William Fogg Osgood and William Casper Graustein (1921). Incidentally, I happen to have, in fairly good condition, original published hard copy versions of both books, **(continued)**

Comment: courtesy of the fact that such books can now be fairly easily located and purchased on the internet. I doubt I would have ever come across either of these books in a used bookstore, even some of the very good stores that I frequented in the 1970s and 1980s (such as [this one](https://indyweek.com/culture/art/durham-s-book-exchange-closes-doors/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are large numbers of books available in the market for learning mathematics or the geometry. But to be good at this, you should start from basic level such as following CBSE curriculum in India. websites like link http://www.khanacademy.com or http://www.studyrankers.com/  can help you in this. These websites have solutions to NCERT, tips and tricks for Maths including solution to RD Sharma, RS Aggarwal and cover many topics. Thanks.